# Change the median value by changing first 'n' values in dataframe R

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

I have a dataframe as follows,

```
data = data.frame(name=letters, values = c(0.183487333,0.487690292, 0.510321455,0.616632727, 0.660789818, 0.845322255, 0.867910555, 0.911842909, 0.913312571, 1.017638286, 15.97454546, 16.20765382, 16.27542982, 16.307264, 17.38325527, 17.54139927, 70.08443928, 70.26106764, 75.79405382, 77.72412946, 79.58750724, 84.67373672, 87.04692364, 88.58626037, 94.79392582, 100.0000))
data = data %>% mutate(diff = abs(values - median(values)), rank_diff = dense_rank(diff)) %>% arrange(diff)
```

head(data)

> head(data)

```
  name   values       diff rank_diff
1    n 16.30726 0.01591709         1
2    m 16.27543 0.01591709         2
3    l 16.20765 0.08369309         3
4    k 15.97455 0.31680145         4
5    o 17.38326 1.09190836         5
6    p 17.54140 1.25005236         6

> median(data$values)
[1] 16.29135
```

I have name and values column, and I have created diff column, by taking the absolute difference with the median value of values and then ranked it based on difference.

The idea here is to change the median value to a new value, by taking the least number of values. Ideally I would like to have a function where I can pass the dataframe with new median value and number of rows to take. Once we pass the number of rows, the values should be changed equally in the first N rows, so that the median value of the entire column, becomes new median value.

My function is as follows, data would be the dataframe, value would be the new median value and rows would be the number of rows.

```
fun <- changemedian(data, value, rows) {
}
```

Here suppose if I passing value as 16.5 and rows as 5, I want the values of the first 10 rows to change equally so that, the median value would be equal to 17. Since I have ranked the DF based on the absolute diff, each difference I make to the values, has some change in median value. I have tried to change .5 in first 5 values, to make it 16.5 and it is working in excel.

I am trying to do this in R using various ways, without much success. Can anybody help me in doing this. Any sought of idea would help.

Thanks

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the question, so bear with me. Is the goal to change data appearing in the `value` column so that the median of `value` is some _pre-specified_ number? And furthermore, we're tyring to do this by changing the fewest number of entries in the `value` column; is that correct?

Comment: @paulstey yes you have understood it correctly,